# $W^{1,p} $ and $W^{2,p}$ Estimates.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the beginning of section 4 in [here](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~lwang/cccalderon.pdf) the author says that one can easily adapt the methods in the preceding section to obtain $W^{1,p}$ estimate. I'm trying to do this. I think the following: the lemma 7 is replaced by

> > **Lemma:** There is a constant $N_1$ so that for any $\varepsilon >0, \exists \delta = \delta(\varepsilon)>0$  and if $u$ is a solution of
> >     $$ \Delta u = f \quad \mbox{in}\quad \Omega,$$
> >     in a domain $\Omega \supset B_4,$ with 
> >     $$\left \{\mathcal{M}(|f|^2) \le \delta^2\right \} \cap \left \{\mathcal{M}(|\nabla u|^2) \le 1 \right \} \cap B_1 \neq \emptyset$$
> >     then
> >     $$|\left \{ \mathcal{M}(|\nabla u|^2)>N_1^2 \right \} \cap B_1| < \varepsilon |B_1|.$$

Here $$\mathcal{M}v(x) = \sup_{r>0}\dfrac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}|v|$$
is the maximal function of $v.$
As in [here](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~lwang/cccalderon.pdf) there is a point $x_0 \in B_1$ so that
$$ \dfrac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|}\int_{B_r(x_0)} |\nabla u |^2 \le 1  \quad \mbox{and } \quad \dfrac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|}\int_{B_r(x_0)}|f|^2 \le \delta^2$$
and consequently
$$ \int_{B_4} |\nabla u|^2 \le 2^n \quad \mbox{and} \quad \int_{B_4}|f|^2 \le 2^n \delta^2  \tag{1}$$
by Poincaré and the first inequality we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{B_4}|  u - \overline{u}_{B_4}|^2 \le C_1
\end{equation}
In lemma 7 in the same way we get
\begin{equation}
\int_{B_4}| \nabla u - \overline{\nabla u}_{B_4}|^2 \le C_1
\end{equation}
and considering $v$ the solution of the following equation
$$
\left \{
\begin{array}{rclcl}
\Delta v & = & 0 & \mbox{in} & B_4 \\
v&=& u - (\overline{\nabla u})_{B_4}\cdot x - \overline{u}_{B_4} & \mbox{on}&  \partial B_4
\end{array}
\right .
$$
Then by minimality of harmonic functions with respect to energy in $B_4.$
\begin{equation}
\int_{B_4} | \nabla v|^2 \le \int_{B_4}| \nabla u - \overline{\nabla u}_{B_4}|^2 \le C_1.
\end{equation}
So as $\nabla v$ is also harmonic by gradient estiamte (of the harmonic function $\nabla v$) we have
\begin{equation}
\|D^2 v\|_{L^\infty(B_3)}\le N_0^2.
\end{equation}

Then my intention is also to obtain universal control as below
\begin{equation}
\| \nabla v \|_{L^\infty(B_3)} \le N_0^2.
\end{equation}
Am I right? What should I do? Thank you. I will be very grateful.

Comment: Doesn't the beginning of section 4 states, that $W^{1,,p}$ estimates also hold if the right hand side $f$ is the divergence of an $L^p$ function? I think, in general you can't expect a solution with weak right hand side to be essentially bounded since $H^1$ functions are not bounded in dimension $>1$. Or is this why you need the (uniform in $p$) estimates for every $p$?

Comment: I said that the author said that "one can easily adapt the methods in the preceding section to obtain $W^{1,p}$ estimates". I didin't say $u \in W^{1,p}$ if $\Delta u= f$ with $f \in L^p$. In fact, $\Delta u= \mbox{div}f$.

Comment: Sorry, to me theorem 5 looked like a generalizazion of theorem 4 for weaker right hand sides. And the sentence with the genelerization was in my eyes pointing to theorem 5.

Comment: Sorry if I was rude too. Any comment is welcome.